# React.JS dynamic import of non-default property/symbol

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

```
import BraftEditor, { ControlType } from 'braft-editor'
```

For the default property `BraftEditor`:

```
const BraftEditorNoSSR = dynamic(import('braft-editor'), {ssr: false})
```

How about that for the non-default property/symbol of `ControlType`?

```
./DraftEditor.tsx:11:42
Type error: Property 'ControlType' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/braft-editor/index")'.

   9 | const BraftEditor = dynamic(import('braft-editor'), {ssr: false})
  10 | const ControlType = dynamic(() =>
> 11 |   import('braft-editor').then(lib => lib.ControlType), {ssr: false}
     |                                          ^
  12 | );
  13 | const CLASS_NAME = 'MuiEditor-root'
  14 | const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: @app/lib@0.0.1 
npm ERR!   at location: /project/packages/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

you can import the component like this

```
const ControlType = dynamic(() =>
  import('braft-editor').then(lib => lib.ControlType),
);
```

or you can import default

```
const Braft = dynamic(() => import('braft-editor'));
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How to get the symbols from the `import default` your second solution?

Comment: to import something that you want to use as no-default inside the library, you can use then(), so when it imports the dynamic library, you only get the property/symbol you want, in your case, I think the best solution would be the first solution.

I'll leave the link, where the next explains everything: [Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

Comment: Tried the second solution but the property/symbol is not found.